# Mongos + Pymongo 2.5 ==>No suitable hosts found

Tags: pymongo

Our application is using pymongo. I'm trying to connect to mongos. The code fails on the following line

```
pymongo.MongoReplicaSetClient(ec2-aa-bbb-124-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017,
                                                        replicaSet=self.class_settings['mongo_rs'])
```

Exception

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/.../server_tornado.py --config=conf/development.conf --port=9001
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/..../server_tornado.py", line 319, in 
    BaseCatalog.db_instance = DBInit(config=settings)

File "/Users/..../lib/sc/singleton.py", line 20, in **call**
    cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).**call**(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/..../app/models/db_init.py", line 50, in **init**
    raise Exception("**init**() => " + str(err))

Exception: **init**() => **No suitable hosts found**

Process finished with exit code 1`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, if at all anyone faces this issue:

Using MongoClient instead of MongoReplicaClient fixes the issue. This is because Mongos acts like a single instance of mongodb.